# How to connect CMOS image Sensor to Raspberry Pi

Tags: hardware, camera, connection

I'm wondering if it would be possible to take an image sensor out of an old camera and plug it in to a raspberry pi via the csi connector. For Example would it be possible to take one like this[image] from an old GoPro and bridge it over somehow? If so this would be a great upcycle project!